# Firebase dynamic links UTM parameters

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, deeplink

I have created the firebase dynamic link in Android, I am receiving deep link path using.

```
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent()).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData==null)return;
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData.getExtensions() != null) {
                Bundle ext = pendingDynamicLinkData.getExtensions();
                Log.i("Deeplink","keySet "+ext.keySet().isEmpty());
                for (String key : ext.keySet()) {
                    PurplleTrace.i("Deeplink", "Ket" + key + "value"
                            + ext.get(key).toString()); //To Implement
                }
            }
            Log.i("Deeplink", pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink().toString());
            Log.i("Deeplink", "" + pendingDynamicLinkData.getMinimumAppVersion());

        }
    });
```

How to get UTM parameters source, medium, campaign  params  from the link

Comment: did you get the solution? I am aslo doing the same thing

Comment: Same thing here! Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @rahul-devanavar Did you find a solution to this issue?